# How to specify an enumeration value in the Word interop?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I'm working on a tool to automate editing in Word documents using Visual Basic .NET. I have referenced the Word library and imported the Microsoft.Office.Interop namespace.

As I'm a beginner I'm first running the example in the following link( https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/313193/how-to-automate-microsoft-word-by-using-visual-basic-to-create-a-new-d ). However, the code in this link is outdated and all references I checked did not help to fix assigning parameters to enumeration methods it gives the following error

> wdcollapseEnd is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

Here's an extract of my code

```
Do 
  oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range
  oRng.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
  oRng.InsertAfter("A line of text")
  oRng.InsertParagraphAfter()
Loop While Pos >= oRng.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
'wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage
oRng.Collapse(wdCollapseEnd)
oRng.InsertBreak(wdpagebreak)
```

How to fix the errors in the above lines?

Comment: Do you use Word's internal VBA-Editor? Then - as mentioned in the linked article - you need a reference to `Microsoft Word x.x Object Library` to use `wd...` ENUMs. Current version is 16.0. BTW you don't "assign" values to ENUMs, but you can use either an ENUM or its corresponding number value (`wdCollapseEnd` or 0 are the same, `wdCollapseStart` or 1 are the same).

Comment: so for example, instead of wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage I put 6, correct?
ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdinformation

in that case why didn't it read wd..ENUMs and only reads the value(lke 0,1,6..etc), when in the sample code they used the wdCollapseEnd not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, code samples for VBA will not necessarily work 1:1 for code in VB.NET. In the case of enumerations it's necessary to **qualify** them - the code needs to tell VB.NET where to find them, or use their numerical (`Integer`) eqivalents.

For example, in the declarations you have `As Word.Table`, which tells VB.NET `Table` is a member of the `Word` library. For enumerations, a second level needs to be specified, the identifier of the enumeration. So the full qualification of the `wdCollapseEnd` enumeration value is:

```
oRng.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd)
```

Or, using the numerical equivalent:

```
oRng.Collapse(0)
```

If the identifier or numerical value of the enumeration is not known, it can be looked up in the Language Reference or in the VBA Editor's object browser (start Word, F11 to open the editor, F2 to open the object browser, type the enumeration into the search box).

Generally, code is more readable using the fully qualified enumeration descriptive name. If late-binding (no reference to the Word library) is used, however, the numerical value is required.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working version of the sample code for visual basic which uses the enum values instead of the names:

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oTable As Word.Table
    Dim oPara1 As Word.Paragraph, oPara2 As Word.Paragraph
    Dim oPara3 As Word.Paragraph, oPara4 As Word.Paragraph
    Dim oRng As Word.Range
    Dim oShape As Word.InlineShape
    Dim oChart As Object
    Dim Pos As Double


    'Start Word and open the document template.

    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add

    'Insert a paragraph at the beginning of the document.
    oPara1 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
    oPara1.Range.Text = "Heading 1"
    oPara1.Range.Font.Bold = True
    oPara1.Format.SpaceAfter = 24    '24 pt spacing after paragraph.
    oPara1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a paragraph at the end of the document.
    '** \endofdoc is a predefined bookmark.
    oPara2 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range)
    oPara2.Range.Text = "Heading 2"
    oPara2.Format.SpaceAfter = 6
    oPara2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert another paragraph.
    oPara3 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range)
    oPara3.Range.Text = "This is a sentence of normal text. Now here is a table:"
    oPara3.Range.Font.Bold = False
    oPara3.Format.SpaceAfter = 24
    oPara3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a 3 x 5 table, fill it with data and make the first row
    'bold,italic.
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range, 3, 5)
    oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
    For r = 1 To 3
        For c = 1 To 5
            oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "r" & r & "c" & c
        Next
    Next
    oTable.Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
    oTable.Rows(1).Range.Font.Italic = True

    'Add some text after the table.
    'oTable.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    oPara4 = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range)
    oPara4.Range.InsertParagraphBefore()
    oPara4.Range.Text = "And here's another table:"
    oPara4.Format.SpaceAfter = 24
    oPara4.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a 5 x 2 table, fill it with data and change the column widths.
    oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range, 5, 2)
    oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
    For r = 1 To 5
        For c = 1 To 2
            oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "r" & r & "c" & c
        Next
    Next
    oTable.Columns(1).Width = oWord.InchesToPoints(2)   'Change width of columns 1 & 2.
    oTable.Columns(2).Width = oWord.InchesToPoints(3)

    'Keep inserting text. When you get to 7 inches from top of the
    'document, insert a hard page break.
    Pos = oWord.InchesToPoints(7)
    oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    Do
        oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range
        oRng.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
        oRng.InsertAfter("A line of text")
        oRng.InsertParagraphAfter()
    Loop While Pos >= oRng.Information(6)
    'wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage
    oRng.Collapse(0)
    oRng.InsertBreak(7)

    oRng.Collapse(0)

    oRng.InsertAfter("We're now on page 2. Here's my chart:")
    oRng.InsertParagraphAfter()

    'Insert a chart and change the chart.
    oShape = oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject(
    ClassType:="MSGraph.Chart.8", FileName _
    :="", LinkToFile:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False)
    oChart = oShape.OLEFormat.Object
    oChart.charttype = 4 'xlLine = 4
    oChart.Application.Update
    oChart.Application.Quit
    '... If desired, you can proceed from here using the Microsoft Graph 
    'Object model on the oChart object to make additional changes to the
    'chart.
    oShape.Width = oWord.InchesToPoints(6.25)
    oShape.Height = oWord.InchesToPoints(3.57)

    'Add text after the chart.
    oRng = oDoc.Bookmarks("\endofdoc").Range
    oRng.InsertParagraphAfter()
    oRng.InsertAfter("THE END.")
```